# Java SQL comprehension

Tags: java

Are there Java classes for manipulating SQL statements?

For example, break this statement

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE a = 1 AND b = 2 ORDER BY 1;
```

into some kind of map.

```
['select' => {'col1', 'col2'}, 'from' => {'table'}, 'where' => ..]
```

Then, you would be able to say add to the where clause or add tables to select from. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:  [zql](http://www.gibello.com/code/zql/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [squiggle-sql](http://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/). It's API is object oriented but you could map it.